# MySql-How to set two alias name to single column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select event_id,
       IF(event_type!='C',e.event_title ,'') event_title,
       IF(event_type='C', e.event_title ,'') event_subtitle
from event e where log_id='%s'
```

this query results only for "event_title", and show empty result for "event_subtitle", even though i have  data for the result "event_subtitle"

Comment: *not working* is not an error description. Please explain in Detail what is wrong

Comment: have you  got any error or not getting your expected output or something else?

Comment: what sql code you want your code does not seem to be from any sql commands??

Comment: What is `e` alias? Your have not aliased your table `event` as `e`

Comment: @isuru89 already do that by OP `from event e where log_id='%s'`

Comment: this query results only for "event_title", and show empty result for "event_subtitle", even though i have data for the result "event_subtitle"
this is because event_type ='C' does not have in any column

Comment: Your code should work can you provide sample data (as text in the question) which demonstrates it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check  this:

```
select event_id,
       case when event_type<>'C' then e.event_title  end  as  event_title,
       case when event_type='C'then e.event_title end as  event_subtitle
from event where log_id='%s';
```

fro example:

```
SELECT ename ,
case when job='SALESMAN' then  ename end as  salesman_ename,
case when job<>'SALESMAN' then  ename end as not_salesman_ename
FROM scott.emp;

SMITH       SMITH
ALLEN   ALLEN   
WARD    WARD    
JONES       JONES
MARTIN  MARTIN  
BLAKE       BLAKE
CLARK       CLARK
SCOTT       SCOTT
KING        KING
TURNER  TURNER  
ADAMS       ADAMS
JAMES       JAMES
FORD        FORD
MILLER      MILLER
H       H
```

Comment: it seems you want this

Comment: Maybe if event is aliased as e

Answer (score 1):

The code 'works' for example

```
drop table if exists event;
create table event(event_id int, event_type varchar(1), event_title varchar(10));

insert into event values
(1,'c','aaa'),(2,'x','xxx');

select event_id,
       IF(event_type!='C',e.event_title ,'') event_title,
       IF(event_type='C', e.event_title ,'') event_subtitle
from event e;

+----------+-------------+----------------+
| event_id | event_title | event_subtitle |
+----------+-------------+----------------+
|        1 |             | aaa            |
|        2 | xxx         |                |
+----------+-------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If your data model does not look like this or the output based on my sample data is not what you expect please add sample data and desired output to the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

You are write `event_title` in both condition but as per your requirement I know that you want `IF(event_type='C', e.event_subtitle ,'') event_subtitle`

Change From

```
IF(event_type!='C',e.event_title ,'') event_title,
IF(event_type='C', e.event_title ,'') event_subtitle
```

To

```
IF(event_type!='C',e.event_title ,'') event_title,
IF(event_type='C', e.event_subtitle ,'') event_subtitle
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you need aggregation:

```
select event_id,
       max(case when event_type <> 'C' then e.event_title end) as event_title,
       max(case when event_type = 'C' then e.event_title end) as event_subtitle
from event e
where log_id = '%s'
group by event_id;
```